# How to have both x and y values on the mouse cursor when you hover on the specific given plot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am having some trouble while printing out unstacked values of x in my plot , so I used numpy arange method to plot with index of x values and name it later with x ticks labels for x axis. But with this method I can't get both x and y values while hovering my mouse cursor on the plot. I have tried using mplcursors module for showing x and y values while hovering.

```
 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
 import mplcursors
 import numpy as np
 x = ['a','a','a' ,'b','c']
 x1 = np.array(x)
 x2 = np.arange(len(x1))
 y = [1,2,3,4,5]
 plt.plot(x2,y,'ob-')
 plt.xticks(ticks =x2 , labels = x)
 mplcursors.cursor(hover = True)
 plt.show()
```

output image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kN8X.png

Comment: Use Bokeh if you want hover of data point values

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way of using hovering in matplotlib in my above graph?